# Option to saving and not saving UTC time in Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

It seems to me that Azure Table always saves UTC time to the table. Even the date type has time zone, e.g. `DateTimeOffset`.

Is there an option to save original time, instead of UTC time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an option to save original time, instead of UTC time?

If you are looking to save the data as `Edm.DateTime`, then the answer is no. That data is always stored as UTC.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#property-types) about Edm.DateTime:

> A 64-bit value expressed as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The
> supported DateTime range begins from 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601
> A.D. (C.E.), UTC. The range ends at December 31, 9999.

One option for you could be to save the local date/time as `String` type data or convert the local date/time value to ticks and save that as `Int64` and then do the conversion in your application.

Comment: Which one is faster by searching by `String` or `Int64`? Is there any reference?