# Performance comparison of Searching via String or Int64 for DateTime type with Azure Table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I need to search by `DateTimeOffset` type of local time on Azure Table.

My question is that if local time of `DateTimeOffset` type is saved as `RowKey`, which type is faster in indexing and searching by `RowKey`, `String` or `Int64`?

By `Int64`: `DateTimeOffset` has to convert to integer type.

PartitionKey can be any, e.g. date,

Please see [Save locale time on Azure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725583/option-to-saving-and-not-saving-utc-time-in-azure-table)

Answer (score 0):

> which type is faster in indexing and searching by RowKey, String or Int64?

Azure table storage's query performance is no matter with row key type.

You can refer to the following ways to optimize queries for the Table service:

1.Store multiple copies of each entity using different RowKey values (**in the same partition**) to enable fast and efficient lookups and alternate sort orders by using different RowKey values.

2.Store multiple copies of each entity using different RowKey values **in separate partitions or in separate tables** to enable fast and efficient lookups and alternate sort orders by using different RowKey values.

3.Maintain index entities to enable efficient searches that return lists of entities.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query).

Comment: Are you saying that it is the same speed for String and Int64 types?

Comment: Please can you elaborate on point 3? I came across the link already.

Comment: Suggest you to use `string` as rowkey type.

Comment: Can you explain why `string`?

Comment: As the article I provided, when RowKey is Employee id, it still use string as type.

Comment: Do you have an example that shows saving a `DateTimeOffset` or `DateTime` as Integer or string type?

Comment: By `Int64`: `DateTimeOffset` has to convert to integer type.

Comment: You could reopen an issue to distinguish two questions.